# How many integers of $ m $ digits are equal to the sum of the $ m $ -th powers of their digits in the interval $[1, ..., 10 ^ 7]$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was checking the following number theory excercise:

> The number $1634$ has an interesting property. This 4-digit number satisfies that the sum of the fourth powers of its digits gives the same number. That is, $1 ^ 4 + 6 ^ 4 + 3 ^ 4 + 4 ^ 4$ $=$ $1634$. How many integers of $ m $ digits are equal to the sum of the $ m $ -th powers of their digits in the interval $[1, ..., 10 ^ 7]$? 
>   What is the largest of those complies with said property in the same interval?

I've found using some research that the numbers under the power of four are:

$$1634 = 1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4$$
$$8208 = 8^4 + 2^4 + 0^4 + 8^4$$
$$9474 = 9^4 + 4^4 + 7^4 + 4^4$$

As $1 = 1^4$ is not a sum it is not included.

So my biggest number is $9474$ in this moment.

Is there a bigger number than that or other number that that meets the condition of the statement in the interval provided?

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A005188](https://oeis.org/A005188) and links there.

Comment: Note that for any given exponent you only need to check up to some number of digits.  For exponent $k$ and $m$ digits the greatest the sum can be is $m9^k$, but an $m$ digit number is at least $10^{m-1}$.  Roughly when $m \gt k$ you have $10^{m-1} \gt m9^k$ and you are done with that $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following Java code:

```
public class Test {
    public static final long LIMIT = 10_000_000L;

    public static int len(long number) {
        return String.valueOf(number).length();
    }

    public static long pow(long number, int exp) {
        long prod = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < exp; i++) {
            prod *= number;
        }
        return prod;
    }

    public static long sum(long number) {
        int m = len(number);
        long s = 0;
        while(number > 0) {
            long digit = number % 10;
            s += pow(digit, m);
            number /= 10;
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(long num = 10; num < LIMIT; num++) {
            if(num == sum(num)) {
                System.out.println(num);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
153
370
371
407
1634
8208
9474
54748
92727
93084
548834
1741725
4210818
9800817
9926315
```

Adjust **LIMIT** and you can proceed even further. Up to $10^9$:

```
24678050
24678051
88593477
146511208
472335975
534494836
912985153
```